# Django: how to pass value from a list template to a view, static url

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In my template, I have a list of users on which the connected user can click to access the profile of a user on the list. I want to retrieve the user I clicked on in my view. However, I would like to keep a static URL (to avoid having user-related settings displayed in the URL). Do you have any idea how to do that?

Here is my template :

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
            {% if userConnected.adminRole == "SuperUser" %}
                   <h2>Members List</h2>

                   <h3>Members from OU : {{ userConnected.ou }} </h3>

                   {% for element in user_list %}
                          <a href="edit_other_profile"><p>{{ element.first_name }}</p></a>
                   {% endfor %}

            {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

What should I add to my template and what should I write in my view "edit_other_profile" to get the right user ? Thanks a lot

Comment: The only way to pass information to the backend but not have it appear in the URL is to use a POST request, which needs a form and would be very odd for just viewing data. Why don't you want the username in the URL?

Comment: Well, it means that every user would have an URL. I don't want the users to try to get to a page they shouldn't try to access.

Comment: About the form, is it possible that it does not appear on the screen and that it is automatically filled in with the username that a user has clicked on?

Comment: But you should check the permissions on the view that displays the profile, not rely on security through obscurity.

Comment: Well you convinced me. I'm gonna pass an ID in the URL and check the permissions in the view. Still, I think I will hash theses IDs with md5. Is it easy to pass parameters within the URL ?

Comment: You can simply add if else statement with permission denied according to your requirements in your `views.py` . It will redirect to 403 page for those user who does not have the permission. It is also possible in template itself with a simple if tag, but you have to add it to every single page according to your url.